# Spawn characters in another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity and I'm having trouble getting characters to spawn in another scene. Here's the code I have written:

```
public class HumanSpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private float range = 10.0f;
[SerializeField] private GameObject human;

void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    LevelManager.instance.OnLevelSelect += LevelUI_CreateLevel;
}

private void LevelUI_CreateLevel(object sender, LevelManager.OnLevelSelectEventArgs e)
{
    SpawnHumans(e.level.numberOfPeople);
}

private void SpawnHumans(int numberOfPeople)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfPeople; i++)
    {
        float radius = 10f;
        Instantiate(human, RandomNavMeshLocation(radius), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

private Vector3 RandomNavMeshLocation(float radius)
{
    Vector3 randomPoint = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
    return randomPoint;
}
}
```

And this class:

```
 public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
//singleton
public static LevelManager instance { get; private set; }

//level
[SerializeField] private GameObject levelPanel;
private Level selectedLevel;

//Event
public event EventHandler<OnLevelSelectEventArgs> OnLevelSelect;

private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}
public class OnLevelSelectEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Level level;
}


public void SetLevel(Level level)
{
    selectedLevel = level;
}

public void LoadSelectedLevel(Level level)
{
    //SceneManager.LoadScene(level.name);
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(level.name);
    OnLevelSelect?.Invoke(this,
        new OnLevelSelectEventArgs { level = selectedLevel }
    );
}
```

}

I have a HumanSpawnManager script that is responsible for spawning characters (human) based on the number of people specified in the Level object. The Level object is passed through an event from the LevelManager script.

The issue I'm facing is that when the new scene is loaded, the characters don't spawn. It seems like the HumanSpawnManager is not executing the SpawnHumans method in the new scene. How can I ensure that the characters are spawned in the new scene after it is loaded?

The error Unity throws is: Failed to create agent because there is no valid NavMesh. I believe this is because the characters are trying to spawn before the navmesh from another scene is loaded.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried spawning the Humans in the next scene normally? As in running that as the starting scene rather than switching scenes

Comment: Before being able to help, we need to know where are these two classes located;
Is there only one LevelManager or is there one in each Level scene?
Same goes for HumanSpawnManager.

Are you sure the SpawnHumans method is not executed?
If it's not, you shouldn't get errors about the NavMesh.